# What is the effect name to display the message dialog block after record creation or edited in the Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am newbie want to know what is the effect/technique to display the message dialog block after record creation or edited?

Could anyone give me a keyboard thus I can search more information. Thank you.

Is it named 'Modal' or something like this?

**What is the effect name of the orange blocked message dialog -- record creation**
[image]

**What is the effect name of the orange blocked message dialog -- record edited**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a bootstrap notification. You can find more details [here](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/)

Here is a code sample for you from the reference.

```
$.notify({
    // options
    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign',
    title: 'Bootstrap notify',
    message: 'Turning standard Bootstrap alerts into "notify" like notifications',
    url: 'https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify',
    target: '_blank'
},{
    // settings
    element: 'body',
    position: null,
    type: "info",
    allow_dismiss: true,
    newest_on_top: false,
    showProgressbar: false,
    placement: {
        from: "top",
        align: "right"
    },
    offset: 20,
    spacing: 10,
    z_index: 1031,
    delay: 5000,
    timer: 1000,
    url_target: '_blank',
    mouse_over: null,
    animate: {
        enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
        exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
    },
    onShow: null,
    onShown: null,
    onClose: null,
    onClosed: null,
    icon_type: 'class',
    template: '<div data-notify="container" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-3 alert alert-{0}" role="alert">' +
        '<button type="button" aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-notify="dismiss">×</button>' +
        '<span data-notify="icon"></span> ' +
        '<span data-notify="title">{1}</span> ' +
        '<span data-notify="message">{2}</span>' +
        '<div class="progress" data-notify="progressbar">' +
            '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-{0}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<a href="{3}" target="{4}" data-notify="url"></a>' +
    '</div>' 
});
```